# How to hidden/remove the scroll bar in a div?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wonder if it is possible to remove/hide the scroll while the blue div (id="load") is showing (2 seconds). If the answer is yes, how can I make that?

I have tried to use overflow-x:hidden in the blue div (load) and it doesn't work.

The reason why I need to make that is because I have behind this blue div the full website and I don't want people scroll down while the loading screen (blue div) is showing, because they will appear in the midel of the website when the loading screen disappear (after 2 seconds).

```js
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
  var state = document.readyState
  if (state == 'complete') {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('interactive');
      document.getElementById('load').style.visibility = "hidden";
    }, 2500);
  }
}
```

```css
#load {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2000;
  background-color: #29d4e6;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.3s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 2.3s;
  -o-animation-delay: 2.3s;
  animation-delay: 2.3s;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="animated fadeOut" id="load">Loading........</div>
  <div style="height:2000px"> Hello there! full website </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `overflow: hidden`, note the double **d**.

Comment: yes sorry.. I  have tied to use hiDDen and nothing.

Comment: Your code being what it is, you'd have to apply `overflow:hidden` on the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should hide your website content while your blue div is showing

```js
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
  var state = document.readyState
  if (state == 'complete') {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('interactive');
      document.getElementById('load').style.visibility = "hidden";
      document.getElementById('content').className = '';
    }, 2500);
  }
}
```

```css
#load {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2000;
  background-color: #29d4e6;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.3s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 2.3s;
  -o-animation-delay: 2.3s;
  animation-delay: 2.3s;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="animated fadeOut" id="load">Loading........</div>
  <div style="height:2000px" id="content" class="hidden"> Hello there! full website </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use as following.

Hide the `overflow` property relates to `<body>` tag onload and re-enable it after page render.

```js
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
  var state = document.readyState
  if (state == 'complete') {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('interactive');
      document.getElementById('load').style.visibility = "hidden";
      document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].style.overflow = "auto";
    }, 2500);
  } else {
    document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].style.overflow = "hidden";
  }
}
```

```css
#load {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2000;
  background-color: #29d4e6;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.3s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 2.3s;
  -o-animation-delay: 2.3s;
  animation-delay: 2.3s;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="animated fadeOut" id="load">Loading........</div>
  <div style="height:2000px"> Hello there! full website </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Update:**
or else you could define a CSS Class/ID for the main content and hide it till page loads.

ex:

```
<div id="content" style="height:2000px"> Hello there! full website </div>

document.onreadystatechange = function() {
  var state = document.readyState
  if (state == 'complete') {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('interactive');
      document.getElementById('load').style.visibility = "hidden";
      document.getElementById('content').style.visibility = "visible";
    }, 2500);
  } else {
    document.getElementById('content').style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this effect through CSS alone, by using two `@keyframe` animations.

**Working example:**

```css
body {
position: relative;
height: 400vh;
margin: 0;
padding: 6px;
animation: noScrollBar 3s linear;
}

.loading {
position: absolute;
display: block;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 12;
width: 0;
height: 0;
padding: 6px;
background-color: #29d4e6;
opacity: 0;
pointer-events: none;
animation: loading 3s linear;
}

.loading::before {
content: 'Loading...';
}

@keyframes noScrollBar {
  0% {position: fixed;}
100% {position: fixed;}
}

@keyframes loading {
  0% {width: 100vw; height: 100vh; opacity: 1;}
100% {width: 100vw; height: 100vh; opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<p>Hello there! full website</p>
<div class="loading"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

Script

```
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
  var state = document.readyState
  if (state == 'complete') {
    setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('interactive');
    document.getElementById('load').style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById('inner-content').style.height = '2000px';

    }, 2500);
  }
}
```

CSS

```
#load {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2000;
  background-color: #29d4e6;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.3s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 2.3s;
  -o-animation-delay: 2.3s;
  animation-delay: 2.3s;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="animated fadeOut" id="load">Loading........</div>
<div style="" id="inner-content"> Hello there! full website </div>
```